# How to test apprequest of Facebook SDK if the target iPhone app is not available on App Store?

Tags: ios, facebook

My case is that,
I'm developing a iPhone app which would send Facebook apprequest to the user's friends to invite them to use this app.

So, I created an app on Facebook developer platform and setup "Native iOS App", including

1. iOS Bundle ID - which is got from my iPhone dev center
2. iPhone App Store ID - I put an available ID which is on the market, not the one I'm developing.
3. iPad App Store ID - (empty)
4. iOS SSO Setting - Enabled
5. iOS Native Deep Linking - Enabled
6. Scheme Suffixes - (empty)

OK. Then.

My developing iPhone app right now can send apprequest via Facebook SDK and the user's friends did received notifications on their Facebook iPhone app on their phones. However, after clicking the notification on the Facebook iPhone app on the user's phone, there are two scenarios. One is that my developing iPhone app would be launched if the app is installed on the phone. This is correct behavior as described in Facebook developing guide and it works smoothly.

The second scenarios should be that the App Store sould be launched if my developing app is not installed on that phone. But it doesn't happen in my case. After screen switches, Facebook iPhone app is closed and App Store is not launched. It's odd.

So, I tried to verify each part of code and settings in my Facebook dev center and they look good, except that the "iPhone App Store ID and iOS Bundle ID are NOT belonged to the same App".

So, I rewrite one of my iPhone app (e.g. 2nd App) to support Facebook functions, including invitation function. Setup Facebook Dev center for the 2nd App. 
After receiving and clicking the notification on iPhone, make sure my 2nd App is not installed on the phone, App Store is launched and my 2nd is shown and ready to download.

So, I'm confused. I don't want to release app before I make sure every function is work. How do you make sure your users would be led to App Store as your app is NOT available on App Store?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: +1 I am stuck in same scenario, Please let me know if found any solution.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there is something wrong in my Facebook Dev Center.

Even I put the same settings with my 2nd App into 1st App, it doesn't work.

Then I delete the 1st App and re-create it with the same name, and put the same settings again, it works.

I am not sure what causes it but this solution works for me.

Comment: Hello Lin, I am stuck in same situation, when i select facebook notification, it always launch itune store not open my installed app. Please help me if you can. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to check your URL Schemes in your app's plist. Make sure your url scheme matches your FacebookAppID. 

For example, your FacebookAppID is "xxxxxxxx", and your url scheme should be "fbxxxxxxxx". And add your suffix if you have one, like "fbxxxxxxxxfree"

The key point to launch your app via Facebook notification is that make sure the url scheme is correct. Hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: @lvan Thanks,+1 I have tried with changes in App setting on facebook and suddenly it start working :)don't know what to say Amazing or Worst!